# Why to pass function as an argument to other function, if we can simply call it for implementation?

Tags: swift, function, methods

I am unable to understand the reason what is the point to add this functionality.

Method which is to be passed as an argument or to be called by another method

```
func add(_ a : Int, _ b : Int) -> Int {
    return a + b 
}
```

when calling a function from other function

```
func average(_ a : Int, _ b : Int) -> Int{
    return add(a, b) / 2
}
```

when passing function as an argument to other function

```
func averageArg(_ plus: (Int, Int) -> Int, _ a: Int, _ b : Int) -> Int {
    return plus(a, b) / 2
}
```

Comment: Can you give us some context? Where is this code used, and to what purpose?

Comment: This code is just an example. I was going through the documentation of Swift and came across this concept "function type as parameter."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason to take a function as an argument is that it makes your function more flexible.  It lets the *caller* decide what `plus` does by passing a function or closure that combines two `Int` values to return an `Int` value.

For instance, suppose the caller wants `plus` to multiply the values:

```
print(averageArg(*, 5, 6))
```

> ```
> 15
> ```

or take the `max` of the two values (by passing a closure):

```
print(averageArg({ max($0, $1) }, 1, 100))
```

> ```
> 50
> ```

---

A better example of this is the Swift function [`sorted(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted). `sorted` takes a closure which determines what `areInIncreasingOrder` means.  This allows you to sort an array in increasing and decreasing order by just changing the function passed:

```
[1, 3, 2, 4].sorted(by: <)
```

> ```
> [1, 2, 3, 4]
> ```

```
[1, 3, 2, 4].sorted(by: >)
```

> ```
> [4, 3, 2, 1]
> ```

Here's an example using a function:

```
func shortNamesFirst(_ name1: String, _ name2: String) -> Bool {
    if name1.count < name2.count {
        return true
    } else if name1.count > name2.count {
        return false
    } else {
        // when names are the same length, sort
        // them alphabetically
        return name1 < name2
    }
}

["Chuck", "Bob", "Bill", "Jo", "Ed", "Alexander"].sorted(by: shortNamesFirst)
```

> ```
> ["Ed", "Jo", "Bob", "Bill", "Chuck", "Alexander"]
> ```

The author of `sorted` doesn't have to provide a different version of `sorted` for every type of ordering a user might want.  The user gets to decide what `sorted` means to them.

Comment: So, therefore advantage is: Different functions with different functionalities could be passed as long as it has same structure defined in the parameter of calling function, which get's restricted when we call a function by it's name within another function.

Comment: Okay. Thank you. That was helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

For example, without the function "postProcess" as argument you would have to implement tree functions: getAndAddData, getAndSubData and getAndMulData.

```
func add(_ a:Int, _ b:Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

func sub(_ a:Int, _  b:Int) -> Int{
    return a - b
}

func mul(_ a:Int, _  b:Int) -> Int{
    return a * b
}

func getAndProcessData(_ postProcess:(Int, Int) -> Int, _ a:Int, _ b:Int) -> Int {

    let a2 = ExampleClass.get(a)
    let b2 = ExampleClass.get(b)
    return postProcess(a2, b2)
}

func exampleFunc(a:Int, b:Int) {

    let getAndAdd = self.getAndProcessData(self.add(_:_:), a, b)
    let getAndSub = self.getAndProcessData(self.sub(_:_:), a, b)
    let getAndMul = self.getAndProcessData(self.mul(_:_:), a, b)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not a very convincing use of passing closures around. However, imagine that the implementation is variable, ie. you don't know what should happen under certain circumstances, handling with closures is a great benefit. Take this example:

```
func doSomething(with: AnyObject, whenFails failureClosure: ((Error) -> Void)? = nil) {
  var error: Error?

  // do stuff, maybe setting the error to something...

  if let error = error,
     let failureClosure = failureClosure {
         failureClosure(error)
  }
}
```

This allows a caller to `doSomething` but handle failures of the function in a custom way by passing a closure.

This becomes really useful in asynchronous situations, where the result of your function is used to do something but you cannot run the execution in the same thread (for example, network calls).

```
func doSomethingAsynchronously(completion completionClosure: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
   // Do asynchronous stuff

   if let completionClosure = completionClosure {
      completionClosure()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of swift that isn't used often, but from time to time can come in extremely handy. In your example, it would indeed not make sense, but lets find a scenario in which it actually does make sense.

Lets first look at what `_ plus: (Int, Int) -> Int` means. That piece of code means, that your function `averageArg` is accepting any **closure** or **function** that takes two integer parameters, and provides an integer as output. Because `add(...)` conforms to this requirement (two `integer` arguments and it gives an `integer` as output), you can pass it on as an argument.

But lets look at an example where such a parameter would make sense. Lets say we are writing front-end code for an application which shows hotel-reviews. In this application, we need to somewhere write a function `fetchReviews(_ serverResponse: ([Review]) -> Void)` which obtains all hotel reviews from some remote server:

```
struct Review {
    let author: String
    let rating: Int
}

func fetchReviews(_ completionHandler: @escaping ([Review]) -> Void) {
    // Lets do a request to the server on a separate thread, so that the user can keep
    // interacting with the app. The app doesn't freeze.
    // Making qos .userInitiated will ensure that user interaction will be more important than
    // our backend request.
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        // Do some request to the server....

        //...

        // Lets pretend we have received a response, and we are turning the response into an array of reviews
        completionHandler([Review]())
    }
}
```

Because there can be a (sometimes long) delay between when the server responds and gives all the reviews, and between when `fetchReviews` was called, it would not be nice for the user if the app would just freeze. Instead, you can make the request to the server happen on a separate thread so that the user can continue using the app and the app doesn't freeze (see the `DispatchQueue.global` part).

However, we still want to display all the reviews to the user once we receive a response from the server. By adding the `_ serverResponse` parameter, we can notify whoever called `fetchReviews` as soon as we have actually received the server's response. By doing it like this, the user can keep interacting with the app, and once the reviews become available we can show them to the user!